# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

Im using Django and Oracle, I have to use some table from another Scehma

```
class ModelTable1(models.Model):
    official_id = models.CharField(db_column="ID_OFFICIAL", primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column="COLUMN_X", blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column="COLUMN_Y", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"SCHEMAX"."TABLE1"'
        default_permissions = []
        managed = False
```

When I try to relationship with a model from my schema and running the migration I have this error:
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

My model definition is:

```
class ModelTable2(AuditDataMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    official_id = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelTable1, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="ID_OFFICIAL"
    )
    status = models.CharField(db_column='ESTADO', max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TABLE2'
        default_permissions = []
```

When I went to the table I can see the problem, SCHEMAX.Table1.ID_OFFICIAL is type Varchar2(20) and MYSCHEMA.Table2.ID_OFFICIAL is type NVARCHAR2(20).

What could I do than When I run migration the FK be created like Varchar2?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options. Either try to change the type of `SCHEMAX.Table1.ID_OFFICIAL` to nvarchar or to try to use varchar for `MYSCHEMA.Table2.ID_OFFICIAL`.

While you have to try option one directly on your DB (since managed=False) you can try a [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/) for option two. Here is an example (not tested):

```
class MyCustomField(models.Field):
    def rel_db_type(self, connection):
        return 'Varchar2(20)'
```

Comment: thanks @Marco, I tried but doesnt work! reading the framework code django>db>backends>oracle>base.py there is a data_types dict where are define all the columns types `{'CharField': 'NVARCHAR2(%(max_length)s)', ... }` I changed to `{'CharField': 'VARCHAR2(%(max_length)s)', ... }` and works!!  For now I can work, later I have to see